# How to specify python faust.Record field which name starts with numbers?

Tags: python, json, faust

I'm describing faust model by extending faust.Record class. My input json looks like:

```
{
  "1": "some_string"
  "2": "some_string"
}
```

So I have to create class fields, named with numbers only. I know, it restricted in Python in general, but is there any workarounds, like aliases for my fieds names?

I'm looking for something like Jackson annotations in Java:

```
import faust

class Model(faust.Record, serializer='json'):
    @alias(field_name: '1')
    first_name: str
    @alias(field_name: '2')
    last_name: str
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use a Model class instead of letting the data be a dict?

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to magically salvage a topic without a proper data model.

**You should never write to a kafka topic without a data model.**

As @OneCricketeer suggested, you should ingest the undefined topic as a dictionary.

After that you can write an Agent that consumes this topic, transforms your model to a proper data model and write it to a topic.

```
class Person(faust.Record):
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
```

Now you can start using your e.g. Person model as expected.

```
undeclared_json_topic = app.topic('name_of_your_input_topic')
person_topic = app.topic('person', value_type=Person)

@app.agent(undeclared_json_topic)
async def migrate_to_person(json_stream: faust.Stream) -> faust.Stream[Person]:
    async for json in json_stream:
        person = Person(first_name=json['1'], last_name=json['2'])
        await person_topic.send(value=person)
        yield
```